# condition in html template

Tags: python, html, django

Hello I am working on the web app with Python Django and I am struggling to reate condition in my html template.

I got table and I want to make the text bold in the cell if the text in the cell is equals to specified text. I tried this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>{% if order.order_buffer == 'Buffer' %}{{ order.order_buffer }}{% else %}<b>{{ order.order_buffer }}</b>{% endif %}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    ...
    order_buffer = models.ForeignKey(Buffer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 class Buffer(models.Model):
    buffer = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

views.py

```
class OrderIndex(generic.ListView):
     template_name = 'new_orders/order-list.html'
     def get_queryset(self):
         return Order.objects.all().order_by('-id')
     paginate_by = 50
```

In this condition it goes straight to the else block. Any ideas?

Comment: `<td>{{ order.order_buffer }} {% if order.order_buffer %} {% else %}<b>{{ order.order_buffer }}</b>{% endif %}</td>` ?

Comment: No, no ideas, because you have not told us what `order_buffer` actually is.

Comment: Check  the value of `order.order_buffer`

Comment: @DanielRoseman is string from database. It is 'Buffer' or 'Not Buffer'

Comment: Please show the model and the view.

Comment: @Rakesh why would you think that would work?

Comment: @DanielRoseman models and views added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order_buffer` is a ForeignKey. It will *never* be equal to the string "Buffer". That data is in the `buffer` field of the related model.

```
{% if order.order_buffer.buffer == 'Buffer' %}
```

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you should do the *opposite*, so:

```
{% if order.order_buffer.buffer == 'Buffer' %}
    <b>{{ order.order_buffer }}</b>
{% else %}
    {{ order.order_buffer }}
{% endif %}
```

Right now you put in boldface everything *except* the `'Buffer' text.

Comment: with this condition it goes again to the else block and everything nothing is bold.

Comment: @pipkej: then this is not a string, or it is a string that is not equal to `'Buffer'`, perhaps it is in lowercase/uppercase?

Comment: @pipkej: no the *textual representation* is. But that does not mean that the `order_buffer` is. `order_buffer` can be a (hypothetical) `Order` object for example.

Comment: @pipikej: use the `.buffer` attribute, it would be utterly unsafe to use the `__str__` itself.